# How many hours of training does it take to get decent error in House Prices Dataset using Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, keras, kaggle

I'm new to Machine Learning and I'm trying to implement linear regression using keras on this dataset https://www.kaggle.com/harlfoxem/housesalesprediction . Although I think classical machine learning will be more suited to this problem, I want to use Neural Network to learn about it. I have done feature selection and removed some features with high correlation with each other, and now have 8 features left. I have hnormalized my features, but not the labels. I have read and know that Neural Networks generally take time to train, I just want to ask this question to prevent me from investing further time on a model that might won't work. Right now, I am training a model with this design:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, inputshape = (10, ) , activation =LeakyReLU()))         
model.add(Dense(7, activation=LeakyReLU())) 
model.add(Dense(1)) 
model.compile(optimizer ="adam", loss = "meansquarederror", metrics = ["meansquared_error"])
```

and right now, it's been 13,000 epochs and 8 hours, and I'm still getting : 
loss: 66127403415.9417 - meansquarederror: 66127421440.0000 - valloss: 75086529026.4872 - valmeansquarederror: 75086495744.0000

Although I can see that the loss has been slowly improving (It started at about 300 billion) . So how many hours of training does it take to get decent error on this dataset? Am I on the right track?

Comment: The training time varies depending on the various factors: Maily number of trainable model parameters, which indeed depends on your model size, followed by the training data, epochs, etc. One thing to note is the Hardware, which can be CPU or GPU or TPU, Trainings on CPU is very slow.

Comment: In simple terms, you can roughly and vaguely calculate by (total_no_of_epochs * Unit_time)/(Epochs_per_unit_time). If you consider 10 epochs per 1 hour, then (total_no_of_epochs*1)/(10)

Comment: Thanks for the response! My question is is the 300 billion starting loss normal? And the rather slow decrease of loss after 13,000 epochs?

Comment: Reducing loss is normal, and yes you can expect it to reduce at the faster pace in initial stages and then at the slower pace. The loss value depends on the loss function or objective that you are using. It sounds a bit too much for me, but I have not used MSE as loss, so I cannot judge over it.